# extending the Craft control panel templates are unstyled

Tags: templating, modules

First time building a custom control panel dashboard for a module.

Template loads ok but is unstyled and not loading JS that the rest of the control panel screens do.

```
{% extends "_layouts/cp" %}
{% set title = "Dashboard"|t %}

{% block content %}
    hello
{% endblock %}
```

what have I missed from https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/cp-templates.html#page-templates

the controller for this looks like

```
return Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate('module/cp/charges/index');
```

Comment: props to Leevi Graham who suggested doing return $this->asCpScreen()
            ->title('Charges')
            ->contentTemplate('module/cp/charges/index'); and works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using:

```php
return $this->asCpScreen()
            ->title('dashboard')
            ->contentTemplate('startupstirling/cp/charges/index');
```

removing blocks from your template so it's just the content:

```
hello
```